# Right image in table not resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have a table with 7 cells, 4 contain images and 3 function as spacing. The image cells do not have a width but the spacing cells do.

```
|image| |image| |image| |image|
```

The container has a min and max width and the table width is 100%, I want the images to resize with the table cells so that the spacing cells stay the same but the images equally resize to fit the cell. I'm creating a partly responsive website that has a min width of 960px and a max width of 1070px, that's why the images need to resize.

The problem is: the last image in the table does not resize in IE & Firefox. It works fine in Chrome.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/hF5qY/

Anyone have an idea or a better way to do this with divs?

Comment: start by **not** using tables for layout, not intended for that...

Comment: Yes I know. But I'm new to responsive design and this was the only working solution for me. Also why I added the last sentence.

I could do this with divs but the problem is getting the text to resize, the icons on the image would also be a font.

Comment: i don't think table is the only solution for this... responders might give you the right answer here, but for the long run, i suggest you have a look at how bootstrap is doing it; it's one of the most extensively used css frameworks...

Comment: don't use tables please!

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a few tips that might be useful when choosing a Responsive Design.

In this case, you could wrap the images within li's, setting the li's to around 23-24%.
Then, you leave the img with 100% width and height:auto.
The remaining % will be used for the 'spacing cells' you mentioned.

Try something like this:

```
ul {
    max-width:1070px;
    max-width:960px;
}

li {
   width:23%;
   margin-right:2.66%

}
li:last-child {
   margin-right:0;

}
img {
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hF5qY/1/)**

it seems that % width on TD will resolve your problem

**CSS**

```
#container td {
    width: 24%;
}
```

Comment: In your example the outer two cells are now smaller (the images also) because the outer images are a few pixels wider than the inner images. Still a better solution though, might be usable with some tweaks.

Comment: well as images are not of same dimensions you need to play with TD and images width. I tried with inline CSS as follows - http://jsfiddle.net/hF5qY/4/ but its more suitable if you keep dimensions of images same for all

Answer (score 0):

well i have tried what you want with DIVS alone .... except for the spans .... its working with IE8 ....

here is my html

```
<div id="container">
            <div id="innercont">
                <div id="cont1" class="cont">
                    <a href="samen-doen.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/frRYKmV.jpg" alt="Samen doen" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>
                </div>
                <div id="cont2" class="cont">
               <a href="samen-veilig.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/IgpVrBz.jpg" alt="Samen veilig" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>

                </div>
                <div id="cont3" class="cont">
                <a href="samen-gezond.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/TdUU0zZ.jpg" alt="Samen gezond" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>

                </div>
                <div id="cont4" class="cont">
                <a href="communiceren.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/KxVqQVu.jpg" alt="Communiceren" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>

                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css ....

```
    #container {
    max-width: 1050px;
    min-width: 640px;
}
#innercont{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.cont{
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#cont1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#cont2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 25%;
}
#cont3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
#cont4{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 75%;
}
```

here is a fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AB8Nk/) hope it helps

Comment: The images are stretched in this example, the containing div height has to resize with the images.

Answer (score 0):

here's how i would do it with divs, this is the best option in my opinion: http://jsfiddle.net/hF5qY/10/embedded/result/

don't mind the `#container` this layout will adapt anywhere in the website. be sure you only have 4 image items, else you will need to adjust the `.cell` width.

hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, your example has the first image smaller than the other three, tested on newest Firefox.

Comment: the images are not the same sizes.. first one is 290x214 and the second one is 283x214. they all have to be the same size and you'll get the desired effect

Comment: ok i get your point, you are right.
the last one was bigger because its parent div had padding-right:0 and this made itlarger then the other 3.as the img inside it has a width:100% it was larger (and higher).